# How to test the Profiles in Bluez Linux?

Tags: linux, testing, bluetooth

Anyone having any idea about testing the Bluetooth profiles available in the Linux systems.
Is there any test suite or programs available in Linux?

Answer (score 4):

You could test AGAINST the official Bluetooth organisation 'Profile Tuning Suite' or PTS tool.
https://www.bluetooth.org/Building/Product/TestProduct.htm

Which, I believe, Bluez has been tested against at various stages and for various profiles.

However, it ain't free.

I can see from the Bluetooth.org website (company registration and login required) that the Bluez stack has been recently qualified (listed 12-June-2012) as a component by Qualcomm against the Bluetooth spec 4.0 + HS.

This was with Kernal 3.0, Bluez 4.93.

Specifically tested profiles and protocols in the qualification:

- Service Discovery Protocol
- Logical Link Control and Adaptation Protocol
- Generic Access Profile
- RFCOMM with TS 07.10
- Serial Port Profile
- Audio/Video Control Transport Protocol (AVCTP 1.3) Target
- Bluetooth Network Encapsulation Protocol
- Generic Audio/Video Distribution Profile - Acceptor, GAVDP 1.2,
  Initiator
- Audio/Video Distribution Transport Protocol - Acceptor, AVDTP 1.2,
  Initiator, Source
- Host Controller Interface
- Multi-Channel Adaptation Protocol - Supports Sink Role, Supports Source Role, Supports Standard Op Codes
- AMP Manager Protocol
- 4.0 Host Controller Interface
- Generic Attribute Profile - Attribute Protocol Supported over LE, Client, Server
- Attribute Protocol - Client, Server, over BR/EDR (L2CAP fixed channel support), over LE
- Security Manager Protocol

Was there a particular profile or protocol you are interested in that is not already on that list?

Comment: I have little bit confusion; Profile Tuning Suite (PTS) can be used for BlueDroid?